# PowerShell to remove text after a special character in URL list

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter list of URL's, where some of the URL's having "**/**" character after domain name (.com or .pl ..etc). I am trying to write PowerShell script to remove any text after "**/**" from the URL.

Tried below scripts, but didn't worked.

```
(Get-Content "C:\Work\url123.txt" -Raw) -replace "/" | Set-Content "C:\Work\url12.txt"
```

// this removes the "/" character and combine the URL's

**Input**

```
www.xyz.com

www.abc.com/dummypage/login

www.123.com/login.php?
```

**Expected Output**

```
www.xyz.com

www.abc.com

www.123.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following if your URLs don't contain protocols.

```
(Get-Content "C:\Work\url123.txt") -Replace "(.*?)/.*",'$1'
```

If you are expected to have protocols in your listings (URIs and URLs), then the following will work:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Work\url123.txt") -Replace ".*//|(.*?)/.*",'$1'
```

Since the `-Replace` operator uses Regex, I'll explain the syntax.

- `.*//`: Matches all characters up to and including two forward slashes.
- `|`: Alternative character (OR)
- `(.*?)`: Match as few characters as possible (lazy matching) and store as capture group 1 (`$1`).
- `/`: Match forward slash literally
- `$1`: Capture group 1.

Comment: **@AdminOfThings : Thank you.. it did work as expected... but I am getting below error when I am storing the value to a string.**

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:20 char:18
+ $c = Get-Content $pathy
+                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: @Spikey, what are you trying to store as a string? If you are trying to store the output as a string, then you can just pipe the whole thing into `Out-String`.

Comment: I am running a function to get the input file and get content then remove the "/", Then I have to pass this to another process.



$a = Get-FileName
if (-Not($a)) { exit } 
$c = (Get-Content $a)
$d = ($c) -Replace "(.*?)/.*",'$1'

Comment: @Spikey, if you need `$d` to be a string, you can do the following: `$d = $c -Replace "(.*?)/.*",'$1' | Out-String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **split**:

```
$a = "ffff/666666/iiii"
$b = $a.Split('/') #is an array with all the substrings separated by /
$b[0] # is the first element
```

result: 'ffff'

one line: `$b = $a.Split('/')[0]`

so the code should look like:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Work\url123.txt" -Raw) | $_.split('/')[0] | Set-Content "C:\Work\url12.txt"
```